# Extrema in two variable equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone explain what a positive determinant of the Hessian matrix of second order partial derivatives at a certain point and a 0 minor determinant of the matrix corresponds to? I know the other cases, for example both being positive corresponds to being a local minimum and so on. Does such a case mean the second derivative test is inconclusive?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of the 2-variable Hessian corresponds to the 2nd derivative of a single-variable function.  In both cases, if the quantity is positive, then the function is convex at that point.

If the dimension is $>2$, the convexity condition on the Hessian (on the matrix itself, not on its determinant) is that it must be [positive-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).